# Count value in multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I want to count every key value in multidimensional array and i want result like

```
[Computer] => 1
[mathematics] =>2
[drawing] => 3
```

I tried following code

```
$count = call_user_func_array('array_merge_recursive', $Array);
```

Here is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [StudentName] => Test 1 
            [Drawing] => 50.00
            [Mathematics] => 40.00
            [Computer] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [StudentName] => Test 2  
            [Mathematics] => 
            [Computer] => 80.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [StudentName] => Test 3
            [Drawing] => 80.00
            [Mathematics] => 95.00
            [Computer] => 
        )
```

Comment: and the result of your tried code is? What did you expect it to be?

Comment: @Jeff: i want number of record of each key ( but that key should not repeated ), for example ['computer']=>1,['Drawing']=>2,['Mathematics']=>3

Comment: `array_merge_recursive` doesn’t perform counting, trying to use this function makes little sense to begin with.

Comment: _“i want number of record of each key”_ - no you don’t, not according to your specified result. You want the count of where there’s actually a _value_ under those keys.

Comment: array_reduce might be a better suiting function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple solution. It's not the best, because it's some lines which you could reduce by using some of the array functions php provides.

```
$newArr = [];
foreach($Array as $group) {
    foreach($group as $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($value)) {
            $newArr[$key] = isset($newArr[$key]) ? $newArr[$key]+1 : 1;
        } else {
            if(!isset($newArr[$key])) {
                $newArr[$key] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($newArr);
```

Comment: Isn't `empty()` a bit too much to check if array key exists ?

Comment: @Zyigh the OP doesn't want to know if the key exists, but if the value is other than 0, null, "" - as far I can see from the example.